# Can't access parent member variable in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, scope

I'm trying to access a parent member variable from an extended class. But running the following code...

```
class Mother(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._haircolor = "Brown"

class Child(Mother):
    def __init__(self): 
        Mother.__init__(self)   
    def print_haircolor(self):
        print Mother._haircolor

c = Child()
c.print_haircolor()
```

Gets me this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Mother' has no attribute '_haircolor'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're mixing up class and instance attributes.

```
print self._haircolor
```

Answer (score 24):

You want the instance attribute, not the class attribute, so you should use `self._haircolor`.

Also, you really should use `super` in the `__init__` in case you decide to change your inheritance to `Father` or something.

```
class Child(Mother):
    def __init__(self): 
        super(Child, self).__init__()
    def print_haircolor(self):
        print self._haircolor
```

Comment: What is `super()`'s behavior when confronted with multiple inheritance? Does the usual MRO kick in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance